# Is it possible to have a custom menu added when calling an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, menu

I am wondering if it is possible to keep my application's option menu available even when the application calls an intent which brings up the contact list? I would like my settings option to be available everywhere within the application.

Comment: what do you mean by "available everywhere within the application"? do you mean on all activity on your app? or everywhere on any app?

Answer (score 0):

You menu will only be available in your app , other apps cant use it. To make sure every activity has a menu create the menu in a base Activity Class and make all your activities extent it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same menu show on every activity simply by inflating it in each activity. It will be even more clean if you subclass Activity and give it this functionality.